# string aggregation in Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, string, oracle10g, string-aggregation

How to aggregate string( concatenate) with Oracle 10g SQL?

Comment: Aggregation and concatenation are not quite the same thing. Which did you mean?

Comment: what I ment was to aggregate where aggregation function is concatenation.

let's say data table looks like this:

class text
A     TEXT1
A     TEXT2
B     TEXT3
B     TEXT4

I would like to have group by query 
select class, function(text)
  from TABLE
group by class
that results with something like:
A     TEXT1, TEXT2
B     TEXT3, TEXT4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the collect function:

http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=306

Some other tricks are here:

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php

...If you actually mean concatenation instead of aggregation then take everyone else's advice and use the `||` operator between the two strings:

```
select 'abc'||'def' from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough, it's the "||" operator:

```
field1 || field2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `||` operator. Ex: `'First' || 'Second'`

Also the function `CONCAT(var1, var2)` allows you to concatenate two VARCHAR2 characters. Ex: `CONCAT('First', 'Second')`

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate: [CONCAT](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/functions21a.htm#SQLRF00619) or [||](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/operators4.htm#997790)

Aggregate: [COLLECT](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions024.htm#i1271564)

Answer (score 0):

There is an undocumented function `wm_concat` that you can use. Another option would be to roll your own. `LISTAGG` isn't available in 10g, I think.